# Prove $f'(z)=f(z)$ implies $f(z)=ce^z$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

Suppose that: $$f'(z)=f(z) \text{ for all }z\in\mathbb C.$$ In other words, the complex function $f$ is equal to its own derivative.  Prove that there is a constant $c\in\mathbb C$ such that $f(z)=c e^z$; that is $f$ is the exponential function (up to a multiplicative constant).

---

So far, I've tried substituting $f'(z)=f(z)$ into the limit definition of $f'(z)$, to no avail. I'm trying to think of what other simple expressions I have relating $f$ and $f'$, but am not having much success.

Comment: This has been asked here *many* times before, but I'm too lazy to search for a duplicate... Anyway, what's $(d/dz)\bigl(e^{-z}f(z)\bigr)$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-z}f(z)\right)=e^{-z}f'(z)-e^{-z}f(z)$. Substituting $f'(z)=f(z)$, this now says $\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-z}f(z)\right)=f(z)\left(e^{-z}-e^{-z}\right)$, so $\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-z}f(z)\right)=0$.

Comment: ^--- That is definately the simplest way to go and avoid all possible problems with other approaches like $\log f$, $f'/f$ being well defined etc.

Comment: I've added words in the question that will make searching for it much easier in the future. Maybe we'll avoid having unfindable duplicates someday.

Comment: (In that question, there is no mentioning of complex $x$, but the proof is exactly the same, so I think it's a duplicate.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(z) = f(z) e^{-z}$. It's the product of two differentiable functions, hence it is differentiable. By the product rule, $g'(z) = f'(z) e^{-z} + f(z) (-e^{-z}) = 0$. Hence $g' = 0$, so $g$ is a constant, say $g(z) = c$. Therefore $f(z) = c e^{z}$.

Note that a priori, you do not know that the complex logarithm of $f$ is well defined. And in fact it's possible that $f = 0$, so in that case it's really not defined at all...

Comment: I'm stunned, but I can't find a duplicate. If someone finds one, I'll be happy to vote to close.

Comment: I have seen this question like 4-5 times, but can't find it either now:) Anyway, this is the best solution imo!

Comment: Very elegant strategy. Would not have thought to use set it up this way and apply the product rule. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well then, I *did* waste a few minutes searching for a duplicate. Try googling "its own derivative site:math.stackexchange.com".

Comment: Ah, thanks. I stubbornly included "complex" in every search, mostly because I was unhappy with all these proofs using complex logarithm... So I didn't find that one. Voted to close. At least this new question will also catch people who search "complex equal own derivative"...

Answer (score 2):

Re-write as
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{dz} = f
\end{equation}
Thus
\begin{equation}
\frac{df}{f} = dz
\end{equation}
from which (and wlog)
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{df}{f}=\int dz
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\ln f=z+c
\end{equation}
Hence 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(z)&=&e^{z+c} \\
    &=& Ce^{z}
\end{eqnarray}
Where $C=e^{c}$

-----------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------------

Actually, due to comments below and having another look at the question there is nothing regarding $f$ and how well $f$ is defined. Consequently, one could consider
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-z}f(z)\right) = -e^{-z}f(z)+f'(z)e^{-z}
\end{equation}
Clearly substituting our condition $f'(z)=f(z)$ we arive at
\begin{equation}
f(z)(e^{-z}-e^{-z}) = 0
\end{equation}
Consequently
\begin{equation}
e^{-z}f(z)=C
\end{equation}
where $C$ is a constant.
Thus
\begin{equation}
f(z)=Ce^{z}
\end{equation}

Comment: How do you know that $\ln f$ is well defined?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You only need it defined locally, I think, which is completely unproblematic.

Comment: Note that $C \neq 0$ therefore, for obvious reasons, you miss the solution $f =0$.

Comment: Good points well made, I re-edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\frac{d}{dz} \ln[f(z)] = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = 1 
$$

Comment: How do you know that $\ln f$ is well-defined?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Assume that $f \neq 0$.  Certainly, there's an open set on which $f(z) \neq 0$.  On this open set, we can select a suitable branch of $\ln$.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should show that the function is holomorphic (by using Cauchy-Riemann differential equations).
Then, from a theorem in complex analysis, above differential equation can be solved by the separation of variables.
To show the other direction, simply substitute the function $f(z) = ce^z$ into the equation $f'(z) = f(z)$.